# Web crawler Using Twisted

Tags: python, web-crawler, twisted

I am trying to create a web crawler with python and twisted.What happend is that at the time of calling 
    `reactor.run()`

I don't know all the link to get.
so the code goes like:

```
def crawl(url):
    d = getPage(url)
    d.addCallback(handlePage)
    reactor.run()
```

and the handle page has something like:

```
def handlePage(output):
    urls = getAllUrls(output)
```

So now I need to apply the crawl() on each of the url in urls.How do I do that?Should I stop the reactor and start again?If I am missing something obvious please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to stop the reactor.  You just want to download more pages.  So you need to refactor your `crawl` function to not stop **or** start the reactor.

```
def crawl(url):
    d = getPage(url)
    d.addCallback(handlePage)

def handlePage(output):
    urls = getAllUrls(output)
    for url in urls:
        crawl(url)

crawl(url)
reactor.run()
```

You may want to look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) instead of building your own from scratch, though.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was that simple!!